# jsp ajax call throwing 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: ajax, jsp

I am attempting ajax call on change of a value in .jsp which is as follows:-

```
    $(".custodianautocomplete").change(function() {
    $('#custodianIDSelected').html($(this).val());      
    var IDSelected = $(this).val();     
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {        
      xRequest1 = new XMLHttpRequest();        
    } else {        
      xRequest1 = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");        
    }        
    xRequest1.onreadystatechange = function() {        
      if ((xRequest1.readyState == 4) && (xRequest1.status == 200)) {        
        $(this).parent("td").next().find("input[name=hall_location]").val(xRequest1.responseText);        
      }        
    }        
    xRequest1.open("get", "/chbs/adm/getEmpName.jsp?q=" + IDSelected, "true");        
    xRequest1.send();        
});
```

The execution of the webpage does not even reach `getEmpName.jsp` and an error as follows is shown in console

```
updateHallNames.jsp:254 GET http://localhost:8080/chbs/adm/getEmpName.jsp?q=ISRO008 500 (Internal Server Error)
(anonymous) @ updateHallNames.jsp:254
dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:1627
q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:1589
```

The line No 254 shown in `updateHallNames.jsp:254` is pointing at `xRequest1.send();`

I am unable to figure out the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the error. The problem was with the error in the code of `getEmpName.jsp`. I found the details of the error by using standard `ajax` functionality with `.fail()`. The amended code is available at the link
[**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48607895/jsp-retrieve-data-from-mysql-when-html-value-changes)