# jsp retrieve data from MySQL when HTML value changes

Tags: mysql, ajax, jsp

I have retrieved records from MySQL and displayed them in HTML Table. The HTML Code looks like this

```
<table id="hallTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 10px; display:none;">#</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 20px;">Sl No</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 60px;">Hall Name/Number</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 50px;">Seating Capacity</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 75px;">Hall Location</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 60px;">Custodian ID</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 75px;">Custodian Name</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 60px;">Approver ID</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 75px;">Approver Name</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 10px; display:none ;">Amended</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody name="tblBody" id="tblBody">
    <tr>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 10px; display: none;">
        <input type="number" id="table_id" name="table_id" class="form-control" value="5">
      </td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 20px; font-weight: normal; text-align: center">1</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 60px; font-weight: normal;">
        <input type="text" id="hall_name" name="hall_name" class="form-control" onkeyup="rowEdited($(this).parent())" value="PPEG-VC">
      </td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 50px; font-weight: normal; text-align: center">
        <input type="text" style="text-align: center" id="hall_capacity" name="hall_capacity" onkeyup="rowEdited($(this).parent())" class="form-control" value="50">
      </td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 75px; font-weight: normal; text-align: center">
        <input type="text" id="hall_location" name="hall_location" onkeyup="rowEdited($(this).parent())" class="form-control" value="main" building="">
      </td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 75px; font-weight: normal; text-align: center">
        <input type="text" id="custodianName" name="custodianName" placeholder="Custodian Name" class="form-control custodianautocomplete ui-autocomplete-input" value="ISRO003" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 75px; font-weight: normal; text-align: center">
        <input type="text" id="hall_location" name="hall_location" onkeyup="rowEdited($(this).parent())" class="form-control" value="main" building="">
      </td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 75px; font-weight: normal; text-align: center">
        <input type="text" id="custodianName" name="custodianName" placeholder="Custodian Name" class="form-control approverautocomplete ui-autocomplete-input" value="ISRO005" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 75px; font-weight: normal; text-align: center">
        <input type="text" id="hall_location" name="hall_location" onkeyup="rowEdited($(this).parent())" class="form-control" value="main" building="">
      </td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 10px; display: none ;">
        <input type="text" id="amended" name="amended" class="form-control">
      </td>
      <script>
        attachCustodianAutocomplete();
        attachApproverAutocomplete();

      </script>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 10px; display: none;">
        <input type="number" id="table_id" name="table_id" class="form-control" value="4">
      </td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 20px; font-weight: normal; text-align: center">2</td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 60px; font-weight: normal;">
        <input type="text" id="hall_name" name="hall_name" class="form-control" onkeyup="rowEdited($(this).parent())" value="MISD-NVC">
      </td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 50px; font-weight: normal; text-align: center">
        <input type="text" style="text-align: center" id="hall_capacity" name="hall_capacity" onkeyup="rowEdited($(this).parent())" class="form-control" value="35">
      </td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 75px; font-weight: normal; text-align: center">
        <input type="text" id="hall_location" name="hall_location" onkeyup="rowEdited($(this).parent())" class="form-control" value="MISD">
      </td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 75px; font-weight: normal; text-align: center">
        <input type="text" id="custodianName" name="custodianName" placeholder="Custodian Name" class="form-control custodianautocomplete ui-autocomplete-input" value="ISRO004" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 75px; font-weight: normal; text-align: center">
        <input type="text" id="hall_location" name="hall_location" onkeyup="rowEdited($(this).parent())" class="form-control" value="MISD">
      </td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 75px; font-weight: normal; text-align: center">
        <input type="text" id="custodianName" name="custodianName" placeholder="Custodian Name" class="form-control approverautocomplete ui-autocomplete-input" value="ISRO006" autocomplete="off">
      </td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 75px; font-weight: normal; text-align: center">
        <input type="text" id="hall_location" name="hall_location" onkeyup="rowEdited($(this).parent())" class="form-control" value="MISD">
      </td>
      <td scope="col" style="width: 10px; display: none ;">
        <input type="text" id="amended" name="amended" class="form-control">
      </td>
      <script>
        attachCustodianAutocomplete();
        attachApproverAutocomplete();
      </script>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, I want to update `Employee_Name` whenever there is a change in `Employee_ID`. I tried everything but am not able to achieve it. The `onChange js` code is like this

```
    $(".custodianautocomplete").change(function() {
        var IDSelected = $(this).val();
 $(this).parent("td").next().find("input[name=hall_location]").val(<%=getEmpName("<script>document.writeln(IDSelected)</script>")%>);
    });
```

I have even tried ajax but that is also throwing 500 error. Please help in giving me a solution.

Since there is no response, I am adding additional codes which I attempted.
The modified ajax code is like this

```
$(".custodianautocomplete").change(function() {
    var IDSelected = $(this).val();
    var yql_url = 'getEmpName.jsp';
    var url = 'getEmpName.jsp';
    $.ajax({
        'url': yql_url, 
        'data': {IDSelected: IDSelected},   
        'success': function(response) { 
            console.log(response);  
            $(this).parent("td").next().find("input[name=hall_location]").val(response);    
        },  
    });
});
```

the code at `getEmpName.jsp` is like this

```
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="com.mysql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@page import="javax.servlet.http.*" %>

 <% 
    String buffer = "";
    String emp_id = request.getParameter("IDSelected");
          try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");                     
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chbs?" + "user=root&password=xxx");                              
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT Employee_Name FROM users WHERE Employee_ID = ?;");
            pst.setString(1,  emp_id);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();        
            if (!resultSet.isBeforeFirst() ) {    
                buffer = "false"; 
            } else {
                buffer = rs.getString("users.Employee_Name");
            }
            pst.close();
            conn.close();   
        }
         catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
    return buffer;
}
%>
```

Another type of ajax I tried is like this

```
$.get( "getEmpName.jsp", {
            userId: IDSelected
        }, function( resp ) {
            console.log( resp ); // server response
            $(this).parent("td").next().find("input[name=hall_location]").val( resp ); // server response
        });
```

But the error remains same

```
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3049 GET http://localhost:8090/chbs/adm/getEmpName.jsp?userId=ISRO009 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3049
ajax @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2944
r.(anonymous function) @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:2965
(anonymous) @ updateHallNames.jsp:250
dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:1627
q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:1589
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3049 XHR failed loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/chbs/adm/getEmpName.jsp?userId=ISRO009"
```

I am desperate now because I am trying hard since three days but still not able to hack this. So please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The Happiness of Success is fabulous. 
I made code changes like this

```
$(".custodianautocomplete").change(function() {
        var IDSelected = $(this).val();
        var recovered = "Rakesh";
        // $(this).parent("td").next().find("input[name=hall_location]").val("Rakesh") ;
        //window.alert($(this).parent("td").next().find("input[name=hall_location]").val());

        $.ajax({
             url: 'getEmpName.jsp',
             type : 'GET',
             data : {IDSelected: IDSelected},
             async: false,
             success : function(response) {
                recovered = response.trim();
                },
            fail:function (jqXHR, exception) {
                console.log(jqXHR);
                },
        });
        $(this).parent("td").next().find("input[name=hall_location]").val(recovered);
      });
```

Please note ,

```
fail:function (jqXHR, exception) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                    },
```

This helped me look at errors in `getEmpName.jsp`. Then in Same file i changed if `(!resultSet.isBeforeFirst() ) {`  to `if (rs.next()){` and replaced `return buffer;` to `out.println(buffer);` and `response.trim();` is necessary to remove `whitespaces` from response. And the Code Works The way I Want. Thanks to StackOverflow.com I found all possible ways to debug here itself. I won't mind code improvements if any.